# Getting an instance of a bean excplicitly in runtime

Tags: spring, initialization, javabeans

I have a case where I have a bean (let's call it A) which needs some other bean (B).

This B is retrieved from a static method of a class using MethodInvokingFactoryBean.
This static method depends on the state of the system and will work after the web application is loaded.

I need to access the B only in runtime (no interaction in the constructor).
How can I configure the A to autowire bean B and only initialize it the first time A requires it?

Is using getBean on the Application context the only way?

Thanks!

**Edit - Added some xmls :) **

This is the definition of bean B.

```
<bean id="api" class="com.foo.API"/>
<bean id="B" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="api"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getFactory"/>
        <qualifier value="myQualifer"/>
</bean>
```

This is the definition of bean A.

`<bean id="resources.someRESTResourceA" class="com.foo.MyRestResource"/>`

I can't use Autowire to wire B into A because it will initialize it (B) on A's construction.

B's targetMethod will only work after the web app has been initialized.
I can use ApplicationContext.getBean("B") inside A, but it's not elegant and will be a problem with unit testing unless I do the following (which is also not desired):

```
public BInterface getB() {
 if  (b == null) {
 b = ApplicationContext.getBean("B");
}
return b;
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the question if you could post up an example of your Spring context together with the sample bean code.

Comment: Added some code and xmls.. thanks

Comment: Hi guys, I was struggling with this as well. In the end I found the solution to my problem rather simple: just implement Spring's ApplicationContextAware interface which forces you to implement method setApplicationContext which is called by Spring. Spring puts in the instance of the context. Once you have it, you can then simply get the bean you want using appContext.getBean(). Voila. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

you should lazily initialize bean A.

```
<bean id="A" class="demo.A" lazy-init="true">
  <property name="b" ref="B"/>
</bean>
```

You still need to retrieve the bean A from the Spring container when you need it with the `getBean()` method. It's easily accesible with the [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-aware) interface.

If you autowire bean A into an another bean and that bean is retrieved before bean B is constructed, the Spring container will create bean A at the time it's injected as a property to the another bean.

Comment: Bean A can't be lazy init because it's a REST service that is being created at the web app start up.